# Angular - My controller does not update my component data in the view

Tags: angularjs, controller, components

So, my problem is this:

I have a component that's used twice, and it has a template defined.

Component:

```
.component('topList', {
    template: '<div class="well"> \
                <div class="title"> \
                <h3>{{$ctrl.model.title}}</h3><a href="#" class="close"><i class="ss-delete"></i></a> \
                </div> \
                <div ng-repeat="i in $ctrl.model.items" class="list-question"> \
                <div class="item"><span class="number">{{$index + 1}}</span> \
                <div class="description"> \
                <h4>{{(i.Count/ $ctrl.model.total)*100 | number:2}}% ({{i.Count}} de {{ $ctrl.model.total }})</h4> \
                <p>{{i.Description}}</p> \
                </div> \
                </div> \
                </div> \
                </div>',
    controller: TopListController,
    bindings: {
        model: '='
    }
})

function TopListController() {

}
```

Controller:

```
    .controller('myController', function ($http, $scope, $controller, datesService) {
    var ctrl = this;

    $scope.api = function () {
            var date = datesService.getDates();
            $http.get("apicall/date.from/date.to").then(function (response) {
                ctrl.model = {
                    title: 'Title',
                    items: response.data.Items,
                    total: response.data.Total
                };
            });
    }

    $http.get("apicall/date1/date2").then(function (response) {
        ctrl.model = {
            title: 'Title',
            items: response.data.Items,
            total: response.data.Total
        };
    });
})
```

HTML (jade actually):

```
    div(ng-controller="myController as controller")
        top-list(model="controller.model")
```

When the page is loaded, the component is filled with the data from the method $http.get that is called as the controller is created, but when i call the method api() from the html, the data dont change.

Im calling the method api() from another controller.

Comment: You're mixing `controllerAs` with `$scope` inside controller, so you might have confused. You should Ideally place in controller context(`this`). Then you could call method like `ng-click="$ctrl.api()"`

Comment: I dont get it, i forgot mentioning that im calling the method api from another controller.

Comment: Can you explain the "calling the method api from another controller" part? You mean the api method is not in called from the template corresponding with the controller?

Comment: Yes, this method is called from another controller, that controls two inputs, in this case, two dates, and the API request gets a json with information that happened between these days. And I need to update the information on this component.

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need to call `$scope.$apply();` if you use the data you fetch to update the view. you already have watchers set using 2 way data binding
2. this

   ```
   $http.get("apicall/date.from/date.to)
   ```

   should be this (you forgot a `"`)

   ```
   $http.get("apicall/date.from/date.to")
   ```

Comment: I forget the " when editing, and its true i actually dont need the $scope.$apply(), but its not changing the view and i dont know how it works, even after a lot of research.

Comment: do you use `controllerAs` ? looks like you don't if you use $scope. inside your ctrl try changing `var ctrl = this;` to `var ctrl = $scope;`

Comment: Im not using controllerAs.. But I think i'll have to make a research about it.. and I made the change and it not worked..

Comment: can you make a small demo using plunker or jsfiddle ? it would be a lot better then guessing

Comment: Sure, but I wont do it now, im very tired, tryied a lot to solve this problem, but I'll do this tomorrow for sure, and edit my post, thanks a lot man for your time.